# Could not find any version that matches com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.10+

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I've been through many of the stackoverflow posts concerning this type of error - but none work.  I am importing a project that was using gradle .63

An error told me to upgrade to 1.10 because the previous version has incompatibilities. I did as asked and now get this **error**:

```
Could not find any version that matches com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.10.+
```

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.10.+'
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion 19
  buildToolsVersion "19.1"

defaultConfig {
  minSdkVersion 9
  targetSdkVersion 18
}
```

**gradle-wrapper-properties**

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip
```

**build.gradle (for whole project)**

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
gradleVersion = '1.8'
}
```

**SDK Manager**
[image]

**SOLVED**
The problem was I had a library (facebook) in the libraries directory that was also using the old gradle version. I updated that and the build worked. Now I know to upgrade all modules within a project.

Comment: Using your SDK Manager, make sure that your "Android Support Repository" is up to revision 5 and that your "Google Repository" is up to revision 8.

Comment: Android Support Repository is 5 and Google Repository is 8

Comment: In the future, please paste in actual text, rather than screenshots, as it is very difficult to read what you have here. Your `classpath` line in the `dependencies` closure should end with `1.10.+`, and it looks like it might end with `1.10+` (missing a period).

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.10.+' - refreshed project and still get the error "Could not find any version that matches com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.10.+.